# Django admin custom form submission force to select action from dropdown list

Tags: django, templates, django-admin

I want to add a custom form to a django admin-site change list view. As soon as I add a submit button it asking to select the custom action from the drop-down list. I created a separate form with a unique id. Still it look for a action be select. How can I overcome this?

[image]

Here is my template code.

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<div align="right">
    <form id="generate-form" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select>
            <option value="">-- section name --</option>
            {% for section in sections %}
            <option value="{{ section.short_name }}">{{ section.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="from_date" class="vTextField" placeholder="from">
        <input type="text" name="to_date" class="vTextField" placeholder="to">&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="Generate" class="default" id="gen-schedules"
        style="margin:0; height: 30px; padding-top: 5px;">
    <form>
</div>
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you copy/pasted without changing it, you have this because the form tag isn't properly closed: `<form>` should be replaced by `</form>`:

```
...
    </form>
</div>
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Because it's not closed, the browser thinks it's the same form as the the next form, the actions one.

To avoid this kind of problems, I'd recommend relying on Django's forms to generate the right HTML for you, when possible. To help with complex layouts, [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a great library that is very helpful.